# Derivative of $x' A A'x$ with respect to $A'$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

> Let $A$ be a matrix of size $n\times n$ and $x$ a $n \times 1$ vector.  Consider $y = x'AA'x,$ where $y$ is a scalar. I want to compute the derivatives of $y$ with respect to $A'$.

---

My attempt : write $y$ as

$$ y = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n x_i a_{ik} a_{jk} x_j$$

and take derivative of it w.r.t $a_{j,i}$, where $a_{j,i}$ is the $i,j$th element of the matrix $A'$.  Is it true? If yes, how to get the derivatives?

One possible (tedious) solution?

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial A'} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{11}} & \dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{21}} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{n1}}\\
& & \\
\dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{12}} & \dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{22}} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{n2}}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{1n}} & \dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{2n}} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial x'AA'x}{\partial a_{nn}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
2x_1\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{i1}x_i & 2x_2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{i1}x_i  & \cdots & 2x_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{i1}x_i \\
& & \\
2x_1\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{i2}x_i & 2x_2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{i2}x_i  & \cdots & 2x_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{i2}x_i \\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
2x_1\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{in}x_i & 2x_2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{in}x_i  & \cdots & 2x_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{in}x_i
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= 2 \begin{bmatrix}
A_{1.}' x x_1 & A_{1.}' x x_2 & \cdots & A_{1.}' x x_n\\
& & \\
A_{2.}' x x_1 & A_{2.}' x x_2 & \cdots & A_{2.}' x x_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
A_{n.}' x x_1 & A_{n.}' x x_2 & \cdots & A_{n.}' x x_n
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= 2 A'x [ x_1\; x_2\; \cdots\; x_n]\\
&= 2 A'xx',
\end{align*}
where $A'_{j.}$ refers to the $j$th row of $A'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative with respect to $a_{pq}$ is$$x_pa_{jq}x_j+x_ia_{iq}x_p=2x_ix_pa_{iq}=2(xx^\prime)_{pi}a_{iq}=(2xx^\prime A)_{pq.}$$

Comment: @ JG. Great  answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let scalar field $f : \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f ({\rm X}) := {\rm a}^\top {\rm X}^\top {\rm X} \, {\rm a} = \mbox{tr} \left( {\rm a}^\top {\rm X}^\top {\rm X} \, {\rm a} \right) = \mbox{tr} \left( {\rm X} \, {\rm a} {\rm a}^\top {\rm X}^\top \right)$$

whose [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1861530/339790) is

$$\nabla f ({\rm X}) = \color{blue}{2 {\rm X} \, {\rm a} {\rm a}^\top}$$

---

[matrix-calculus](/questions/tagged/matrix-calculus) [scalar-fields](/questions/tagged/scalar-fields) [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)